# How to convert Server Date format in hour or day?

Tags: dart

**How I will change this date format to in a day or hours**

```
"modifiedTime": "2021-01-30T12:15:14.896Z[GMT]",
"modifiedTime": "2021-01-29T13:58:37.328Z[Etc/UCT]",
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.parse(aString)` should handle a Z suffix for timezone or an explicit offset (-05:00).  To parse other named timezones, you'll need the https://pub.dev/packages/timezone package, which unfortunately has to get updated at least a few times a year because politicians keep messing with things like DST.